# Get image url from mysql using mootools

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, mootools

I'm trying to search a mysql database (made in phpMyAdmin) with a form, with the result updating an image. The database consists of 2 columns, ID (auto-incrementing primary key) and Image (url/path to image). The search only checks IDs.

I'm quite sure the problem is that I'm not accessing the input argument of myRequest.send nor returning the response value onSuccess expects from the php code.

test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UI Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MooTools-Core-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/UI.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var searchForm = new Element('form', {
            id: 'search_form',
            method: 'post'
        });
        var searchText = new Element('input', {
            id: 'search_text',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'name'
        });
        var searchButton = new Element('input', {
            id: 'search_button',
            type: 'submit',
            name: 'submit',
            value: 'Search'
        });
        var image = new Element('img', {
            id: 'image_',
            src: 'res/img/default.png',
            alt: 'Image',
            height: '50',
            width: '50',
            position: 'relative',
            float: 'right'
        });

        var myRequest = new Request({
            url: 'test.php',
            method: 'get',
            onRequest: function(){
                image.set('alt','loading...');
            },
            onSuccess: function(response){
                image.set('alt', response);
                image.set('src', response);
            },
            onFailure: function(){
                image.set('src', 'res/img/fail.png');
                image.set('alt','failing...');
            }
        });

        searchText.inject(searchForm);
        searchButton.inject(searchForm);
        searchForm.inject(document.body);
        image.inject(document.body);

        window.addEvent('domready', function(){
            searchButton.addEvent('click', function(event){
                event.stop();
                myRequest.send('name='+searchText.value);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.php

```
if(preg_match("/^[  0-9]+/", $_POST['name'])){
    $name=$_POST['name'];

    //-connect  to the database
    $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
    //-select  the database to use
    $mydb=mysql_select_db("tutorial");
    //-query  the database table
    $sql="SELECT  ID FROM `image` WHERE ID LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";

    //-run  the query against the mysql query function
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if (false === $result) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    //-create  while loop and loop through result set
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $ID=$row['ID'];
        $image=$row['Image'];

        //-want to return image path here
        echo $image;
    }
}
else{

    echo  "res\img\fail.png";
}
```

EDIT: Having onSuccess change the image alt text to response shows there to be a undefined index error on name in line 2.

EDIT2: Progress! The following php code gets the appropriate image url to be set as the alt text, but the image src fails to change (hence the alt text showing up). How can I get the image src to change properly?

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['name'];
if(preg_match("/^[  0-9]+/", $name)){
    //-connect  to the database
    $db=mysql_connect  ("localhost", "root",  "password") or die ('I cannot connect to the database  because: ' . mysql_error());
    //-select  the database to use
    $mydb=mysql_select_db("tutorial");
    //-query  the database table
    $sql="SELECT Image, ID FROM image WHERE ID LIKE '%" . $name ."%'"; 

    //-run  the query against the mysql query function
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if (false === $result) {
        echo mysql_error();
    }

    //-create  while loop and loop through result set
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $ID=$row['ID'];
        $image=$row['Image'];

        //-want to return image path here
        echo $image;
    }
}
else{

    echo "lulz";
}
?>
```

EDIT3: My bad, I was using backslashes for the image src path... It works fine now.

Comment: I supose you forgot to name the data you are sending. Try `myRequest.send('name=' + searchText.value);`

Comment: That didn't help. Also, I've changed onRequest, onFailure and onSuccess to change the images alt text, it appears the request succeeds.

Comment: Oh, you are using `method: 'get',`, then what do you get when you do `var_dump($_GET);` on PHP?

Comment: array(1){["name"]=>string(1)"2"}           for the input "2".

Answer (score 1):

You don't select column 'Image' in your SQL statement.

Your code should be:
`$sql="SELECT Image, ID FROM image WHERE ID LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";`
instead of 
`$sql="SELECT  ID FROM image WHERE ID LIKE '%" . $name ."%'";`

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem. Making onSuccess change images alt text to response tells me that name is a undefined index.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `method: 'get',` in the MooTools Request class, then you have to use `$_GET` in the PHP.

Replace

```
if(preg_match("/^[  0-9]+/", $_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
```

to

```
if(preg_match("/^[  0-9]+/", $_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
```